# How can I locally debug Facebook PHP applications?

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework

I'm using Zend debugger and PDT for PHP development and have run into an issue debugging Facebook PHP. I'm using the example.php in the SDK to test. The application runs fine from Facebook, but I'm having trouble setting breakpoints. I have tried:

1. Run from Eclipse - Application does not run as expected. I'm getting null values for `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` although I can set breakpoints and debug.
2. Run from Facebook - the application runs as expected, but ignores breakpoints.

I'm using [DynDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyn_(company)#History) for my DNS lookup and have changed my host file to redirect the URL to my local host.

I'm not even sure if #1 is possible, but it would be nice to use Eclipse and not have to refresh a web page as in #2. Any ideas?

Comment: Facebook probably supplies the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] values, so that would be your main issue.

Comment: Seems like #1 is not going to work. Has anyone been able to launch a php Facebook App from a browser and hit a break point on the local machine using zend debugger? If not how are developers debugging Facebook php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a local domain for your local server in the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) of your OS (in Windows you can find it in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`).

For example, if your server runs on `localhost`, add the row:

```
local.mydomain.com 127.0.0.1
```

On the Facebook developers site (in your application settings), set the domain of the application to `mydomain.com` of `local.mydomain.com` and for the canvas URL (if you work within facebook canvas) set the local URL of your application.

For example:

```
Canvas URL: http://local.mydomain.com/my_application/index.php
```

Last, change the Debug URL of the specific page (in Eclipse's menu Run* → *Debug Configuration*) to the URL of the canvas (for example, `http://apps.facebook.com/my_fb_app/`).

Comment: I did the following to get debugging working.

1) All facebook developer settings remain my.domain.com
2) Changed the root server to http://apps.facebook.com in the eclipse debug configuration.

Clicking on test debugger in the debug configuration returns an error about not finding dummy.php but launching the application and hitting breakpoints works.